# Laravel Dynamic pdf Templates html

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I have a working dynamic PDF but my requirement is to customise the HTML of the pdf from the frontend as per the graphics designs.

Can anyone suggest any extension or an approach for handling the functionality?

Comment: refer https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. easy to use.

Comment: I have already used barryvdh, the pdf generation is working fine. I need a functionality which can handle the design of the pdf, more like a theme, dynamic generation of the style/layout of the pdf

Comment: @zimba12_34 how did you solved this ?